# OpenCV can't compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, compiler-errors

I'm a newbie OpenCV user. I'm just trying to learn something about it but I don't know where to start.

Unfortunately I can find a lots of tutorials about openCV but they doesn't work for me (sometime because of the old version they used).

So before really starting I'd like to see if the environment is working fine to avoid wasting time in the future. Here is an example I found:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    //create an image to store the video screen grab
    Mat image;

    //setup the video capture method using the default camera
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    //create the window that will show the video feed
    namedWindow("VideoCaptureTutorial", 1);

    //create a loop to update the image with video camera image capture
    while(1)
    {
        //grad a frame from the video camers
        cap>>image;

        //show the image on the screen
        imshow("VideoCaptureTutorial", image);

        //create a 33ms delay
        waitKey(33);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I try to compile (Visual studio 2010) But I get something like 150-250 errors. I'm new to Visual Studio and I can't understand really well "him" and what he "doesn't like". I'm learning how to move inside the IDE but's its hard.

The errors refers to imgproc.hpp miniflann.hpp photo.hpp tracking.hpp and report a lot of undefined identifiers and syntax errors.

I have some experience in programming (C with Arduino, Java, Assembly) but I found the openCV documentation very confusing and confused. I'm self taught so any help about how to start would be appreciated, my goal is to implement Coputer vision (stereo if possible) into my 2WD robot.

Thanks

Comment: *"I get something like 150-250 errors"* - what errors? compiler errors or linker errors?

Comment: I wrote "The errors refers to imgproc.hpp miniflann.hpp photo.hpp tracking.hpp and report a lot of undefined identifiers and syntax errors. "
100 of them are "intellisense" error and I don't know what is it.

I think they are compiler errors and most of them are ")" missing before ";" or type identifier is missing, it's no more supported in C++.

Comment: The code you have posted seems to be OK, just a little side note: you don't need to `return 0` in C++, that happens automatically. The problem will be most likely in a way these header files are used.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell you what to do to make your program work, since you haven't provided almost any information that would help to understand the cause of your problem. But after reading these lines:

> *I can find a lots of tutorials about openCV but they doesn't work for me (sometime because of the old version they used)*
>
> *I'm new to Visual Studio and I can't understand really well "him" and what he "doesn't like". I'm learning how to move inside the IDE but's its hard.*

I recommend you to have a look at these materials (created by *prof. William Hoff*, *Computer Vision, Colorado School of Mines*):
[Creating Your First Program in Microsoft Visual C++](http://inside.mines.edu/~whoff/courses/EGGN512/lectures/FirstProgramInVisualC++.pdf) and
[Using OpenCV in Microsoft Visual C++](http://inside.mines.edu/~whoff/courses/EGGN512/lectures/OpenCVInVisualC++.pdf)

Also note that binary form of OpenCV is specific for a concrete version of Visual Studio. So for example if you have *...\OpenCV\build\x86\****vc10*** that means that it is meant to be used with Visual Studio ***2010***. I was using OpenCV with Visual Studio 2012 recently and I had to compile it on my own.

Comment: Yes I'm using vc10. I'm also using the x86 but I'm running on a x64 machine.
I don't know what to do, should I copy all the errors I get? They are in italian, so it would be hard.
I tried to describe them but the compiler is not giving me errors on my main.c file but in some others .hpp files. what am I supposed to do, I have no experience with VS 2010 nor with open CV so I don't know how to move.

Comment: I think I'm getting close. The first line of the code where I have #include <>; the cv.h I think It can't find the header. How can I check the right directory?

Comment: @Vendra: *“C/C++” -> “General” -> “Additional Include Directories”*. It's in the second document I gave you links to.

Comment: Yes I saw that, thanks. But what I wonder now if which one of the two include directories should I put there. Because I have one "include" just in the main directory and another one inside the /bin/include.
Inside the last one I also have two more folders one opencv and the other opencv2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have installed OpenCV correctly on you PC and have set up the IDE as you should, you need to include more libraries in your code... Try adding this to the top of your code(I have OpenCV version 3.1 and this code works for me... And I'm a newbie too!)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```