# error convert cv::mat to cv::arr

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

> I'm just trying to learn about OpenCV and i running on a x64 machine.
>
> I am using OpenCV 3.2.0 with VS2015 before and I try to following step
>   by step tutorial from Kyle Hounslow on youtube, but i get error.
>
> then i reinstall using VS2013, but i still got error like below :
>
> ```
> Error 1   error C2664: 'void cvShowImage(const char *,const CvArr *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'cv::Mat' to 'const CvArr *'
> Error   2 IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "cv::Mat" to "const CvArr *" exists
> ```
>
> i already see in link below but still doesn't work for me
>
> > [OpenCV can't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463455/opencv-cant-compile)
>
> i check on link below too, but i got confused
>
> > [how to convert from cv::Mat to CvArr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269742/how-to-convert-from-cvmat-to-cvarr)
>
> my code is like below :
>
> ```
> #include<iostream>
> #include<opencv\cv.h>
> #include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
> #include<opencv2\videoio.hpp>
> #include<opencv2\core.hpp>
> #include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
>
>
> using namespace cv;
>
> int main()
> {
>
>   Mat image;
>
>   VideoCapture cap;
>   cap.open(0);
>
>   cvNamedWindow("window", 1);
>
>   while (true)
>   {
>       cap >> image;
>
>       cvShowImage("window", image);
>
>       cvWaitKey(33);
>   }
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> please help me in that, many thanks.

sorry, i delete the update because the original issue is already solved

many thanks

Comment: `CvMat` accepts `Mat` as an arg in the constructor so: `CVMat imageMat(image);` and then pass the address of this to `cvShowImage`: `cvShowImage("window", &imageMat);`, actually you'll also need to pass the dimensions and dtype so `CvMat imageMat(height, width, dtype, image);`

Comment: **Don't use obsolete C api!** You can refer to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a57c0e81e83e60f36c83027dc2a188e80) for an example on how to do this correctly

Comment: if the original issue is resolved and you have further problems, please open a new question

Comment: sure, i'm sorry

Comment: @RizkySatya and please mark as the answer the answer that solves your problem

Comment: @Miki sure, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing old, **obsolete** C api (`cvNamedWindow`, `cvShowImage`, `cvWaitKey`) with new C++ api (`Mat`, `VideoCapture`). Don't do that. Drop the C api altogether. Everything named like cvFunctionName is obsolete. Use newer api that uses `cv` as a namespace, so names like cv::functionName are what you're supposed to be calling.

In your case it's [`cv::namedWindow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow), [`cv::imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) and [`cv::waitKey`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey):

```
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image;

    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    namedWindow("window", 1);
    while (true)
    {
        cap >> image;
        imshow("window", image);
        waitKey(33);
    }
}
```

Comment: i try what you suggest to me and there is no more error for convert cv:mat to cv:arr, but now there is problem because conflicts machine that i use.
i update the result on above

Answer (score 1):

You should use `imshow("window", image);` if you need to use c++ Mat.

according to [opencv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow)

Displays an image in the specified window.

> C++: void imshow(const string& winname, InputArray mat)
>
> C: void cvShowImage(const char* name, const CvArr* image)